# Json web services return format

Tags: jquery, web-services, json

It may be an easy question but I am wondering how do I get a JSON web service to return the string that has a format like this:

```
var invoice = {
  invoiceItems: [
    { type: 'item', 
      part: '99Designs', description: '99 Designs Logo', 
      price: 450.00, qty: 1 },
    { type: 'service',
      service: 'Web development and testing', 
      price: 25000.00 },
    { type: 'item',
      part: 'LinodeMonthly', description: 'Monthly site hosting', 
      price: 40.00, qty: 12 }
  ]
};
```

What my service returns now is List and it looks like

```
[1,2,2,4444]
[13,444,233]
etc
```

Does the part prior to ':' get automatically appended or do I need to manually do it inside the web service?

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you let us know which server-side language you use. But for sure nothing happens by magic(automatically)

Comment: There are some libraries listed on http://www.json.org, for c# too , for example http://jsonfx.net/download/

Answer (score 3):

JSON is just *text* with a particular syntax. That means your web service needs to output *text* that looks exactly like:

```
{
  invoiceItems: [
    { type: 'item', 
      part: '99Designs', description: '99 Designs Logo', 
      price: 450.00, qty: 1 },
    { type: 'service',
      service: 'Web development and testing', 
      price: 25000.00 },
    { type: 'item',
      part: 'LinodeMonthly', description: 'Monthly site hosting', 
      price: 40.00, qty: 12 }
  ]
}
```

You'll most likely find helpful libraries to convert objects to JSON format (it'll work like a specialised `.toString()`), depending on the language used for the web service. But you'll have to transform the Lists you have right now into something more like a Map in order for the library to output the JSON automatically.

Alternatively, you can build up your own string by iterating through your Lists and simply returning that string as the output.

Comment: I see. What if I use object inside my web service such as: List<Employee> eList = new List<Employee>();
            Employee e = new Employee();
            e.Name = "Minal";
            e.Age = 24;

            eList.Add(e);

Can I refer to the data in this format inside jQuery: Name:Minal ? Or do I need to create the actual text?